# How do I make '"1"' into an integer?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, error-handling, integer

In this case, `p` is a list that is `['  /gene="1"','  /gene="2"',…]`

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-93a440c16f3d> in <module>()
     38 
     39 for i in p:
---> 40   Gene.append(int(i.replace("  /gene=","")))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1"'
```

You see, a simple int() doesn't work. It can't turn `'"1"'` into `1`. Is there a way to turn `'"1"'` into `1`? What is it?

Answer (score 2):

I’d use [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to trim those down like:

```
p=['  /gene="1"','  /gene="2"']
Gene=[]
for i in p:
  Gene.append(int(i.replace("  /gene=","").strip("\" ")))
```

or even:

```
p=['  /gene="1"','  /gene="2"']
Gene=[]
for i in p:
  Gene.append(int(i.strip("/gen=\" ")))
```

or if you don't want to deal with the left side of the equals sign use [partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
p=['  /gene="1"','  /gene="2"']
Gene=[]
for s in p:
    _, _, value = s.partition('=')
    Gene.append(value.strip("\" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the quotes also:

```
Gene.append(int(i.replace("  /gene=","").replace('"','').replace("'",'')))
```

However, I would recommend looking at [RegEx](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) for handling parsing scenarios like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the quotes around the number as well.

```
Gene.append(int(i.replace('  /gene=', '').replace('"', ''))
```